# how to filter or map the object when checkbox event fired and how to set display 'block' when checkbox selected

Tags: angular, events, checkbox, attributes

I'm new to angular 13 and am having some issues and would be grateful for any pointers. On my project there are components for rendering opportunities(opps) object, a component for filter list...etc.
When Event fired, I want to capture the Event.target.value, loop through opportunities object, compare Event.target.value with opp.CATEGORYID, opp.PROVIDERNAME or opp.TAGS and then set display 'block' or 'none' to render on the screen.
In summary, opportunities are already rendered and I want to show opportunities when its display is 'block' but I'm struggling how to set display 'block' or 'none' conditionally.
Thank you so much any advice.

opp-list-component.html

```
<mat-card *ngFor="let opp of opps" 
 class="oppContainer"
 [attr.data-opp-id]=" 'opp_' + opp.PLACEMENTID "
 [attr.data-filters-cat]="opp.CATEGORYID"
 [attr.data-filters-tags]="opp.TAGS"
 [attr.data-filters-provider]="opp.PROVIDERNAME"
 [attr.data-filters-location]="opp.LOCATIONTYPE"
 [attr.data-filters]="opp.TAGS + ',' +opp.CATEGORYID + ',' + opp.PROVIDERNAME + ','+ opp.LOCATIONTYPE + ',' + opp.BADGEASSETID "
 [style.border-left]="'10px solid ' + 'rgb'+ '(' + opp.COLOURCODE +')' "
 [style.display]="displayOpps"
>
   <mat-card-header >
     <img  mat-card-image src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1582213782179-e0d53f98f2ca?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1170&q=80" alt="Photo of a Shiba Inu">
   </mat-card-header>
     <p >
       <a [routerLink]="'/about'">{{opp.CATEGORY}}</a> > <a [routerLink]="'/about'">{{opp.PROVIDERNAME}}</a>
     </p>
 
     <p> 
       <a [routerLink]="'/about'">{{opp.NAME}}</a>
     </p> 
 
     <p textColor>{{opp.DESCRIPTION}}</p>
 
     <p><mat-icon> place</mat-icon>{{opp.DISTANCE}} miles away</p>
    
       <mat-card-footer >
         <p><mat-icon> local_offer</mat-icon> {{opp.TAGS}}</p>
       </mat-card-footer> 
   </mat-card>
```

filter-list-component.html

```
<mat-card-title><h2>Filters</h2></mat-card-title>

   <div class="filter-contents">

    <h3>Category</h3>
    <div  *ngFor = "let cat of cats">
      <p class="bb">
      <label class="cat-label" for="{{cat.CATEGORYID}}"
      [style.border-left]="'10px solid ' + 'rgb'+ '(' + cat.COLOURCODE +')' "
      >
        {{cat.CATEGORY}} ( {{cat.CATCOUNT}} )
      <input type="checkbox" 
      (change)="onChange($event)"
      value="{{cat.CATEGORYID}}"
      >
      </label>
    </p>
    </div>
  

  
    <h3>Organizations</h3>
    <div *ngFor="let provider of providers">
      <p class="bb">
      <label for="{{provider.PROVIDERNAME}}">
        {{provider.PROVIDERNAME}} (  {{provider.PROVIDERCOUNT}} )
      <input type="checkbox" 
      (change)="onChange($event)"
      value="{{provider.PROVIDERNAME}}">
      </label>
    </p>
    </div> 
  
  
  
    <h3>Tags</h3>
    <div  *ngFor="let tag of tags">
      <p class="bb">
      <label for="{{tag.TAG}}">
        {{tag.TAG}} ( {{tag.TAGCOUNT}} )
        <input type="checkbox" 
        (change)="onChange($event)"
        value="{{tag.TAG}}">
      </label>
     </p>
    </div>

  </div> 
  
   </mat-card>
```

search-component.ts (parent component)

```
receiveEvent(event:any) {
 
 this.checkboxEvent = event;
 this.eventValue = event.target.value;
 this.eventChecked = event.target.checked;;
 
 console.log(this.eventValue," this.eventValue from search c!!")
 console.log(this.eventChecked ,"this.eventChecked  from search c!!")


   if(event){
    this.displayOpps = 'block'
   }  

 
   
   //how to do that ??
   //loop through this.opps object

   //check event.target.value === opp.CATEGORYID or 
   //event.target.value === opp.PROVIDERNAME or
   //opp.TAGS.includes(event.target.value.toLowerCase())

   //if false
   //this.displayOpps = 'none'

  

}
```

Comment: please share a stackblitz with the issue replicate, along will screenshots on what you are trying to achieve and what is going wrong! would be more helpful!

Answer (score 0):

there is a few things I would do. Do not hide/show the element using CSS but it's better to completly remove it from the DOM using Angular. How to do this? filter the opps array.

here is some pseudocode, probably there are some errors and fixes to do but you get the idea:

```js
allOpps = [ ADD YOUR OPPORTUNITIES ];
opps = []; // This is the list of filtered oppotunities.
catergory = null;
organisations= null;
tag = null;


ngOnInit(){
    // fill opps at the beginning
    this.onFilterChange(); 
}

onFilterChange(){
    this.opps = [...this.allOpps];
    if(this.catergory !== null){
        this.opps = this.opps.filter(opp => opp.CATEGORYID === this.catergory);
    }
    if(this.organisations !== null){
        this.opps = this.opps.filter(opp => opp.PROVIDERNAME === this.organisations);
    }
    if(this.tags !== null){
        this.opps = this.opps.filter(opp => opp.TAGS === this.tag);
    }

    // now this.opps is filtered and the *ngFor fill show only the correct oppotunities
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm going to try this.